# Python script for MKS integrity query

Tags: python, mks-integrity

I would like to create a script in Python for logging into MKS integrity and calling an already defined MKS query. Since I am a newby in programming, I was wondering if there is any script example for the task. That would be a great help for getting me started. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with python, but for MKS

connect to a host: `IM connect --hostname=%host% --port=%port%`

run query: `im runquery --hostname=%host% --port=%port% %query_name%`

You can see the help for each command if you just write `IM command -?`